# What are Sunbursts used for?

Tags: pc, maplestory

I was hunting Red Goblins in MapleStory when one of them dropped a Sunburst. What is it for? The description only says:

> Flames from the sun that have divine powers to brighten darkness.

Comment: https://strategywiki.org/wiki/MapleStory/Golden_Temple#Sunburst

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 5 Sunburst to enter the Ravana map.

Monsters in the mini dungeons of Golden Temple have a chance of dropping a Sunburst.